# Trouble with Displaying 1D Array Output Correctly

Tags: java, arrays, output, display

My program consists of several options of what to do with user input data about shows (name, day, time). One of the options is to display the data and the total number of shows per day (ex: if there are 2 shows on Tuesday, it will display "There are 2 shows on Tuesday"). So far the output for displaying all the data is working but when it comes to displaying the number of shows on a specific day, it isn't working properly. I've read several other java programs that seem to have a switch statement on each day but that hasn't worked either. If there are any suggestions on what I should change about my code, I would truly appreciate it! Thank you

**I have edited my code from the previous one but it still hasn't worked**

**Note: the int dayCount is placed in the enter data method; after the day[i] = br.readLine();**

Here is my class:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Javavision {

static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
static String name[] = new String[1000];
static String day[] = new String[1000];
static String time[] = new String[1000];
static int dayCount = 0; 
static int x, i, j, smallest;
static String temp;
```

Here is my code:

```
  public static void showShows() {

    //output all shows
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    System.out.println("Name : " + name[i]);
    System.out.println("Day : " + day[i]);
    System.out.println("Time(2:30 am = 0230) : " + time[i] + "\r");

    } **The problem is here**
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if(i ==0) {
        System.out.println("There is " + dayCount + " shows on " + day[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Name : The Flash
Day : Sunday
Time(2:30 am = 0230) : 0125

Name : Suits
Day : Sunday
Time(2:30 am = 0230) : 0450

Name : Java Program
Day : Tuesday
Time(2:30 am = 0230) : 0330

There is 3 shows on Sunday
```

**This is where I increment dayCount:**

```
//Method addShow
public static void addShow() throws IOException {
    //initialize counter
    x = 0;
    do {
    //Update Array
    System.out.println("Enter Name of Show: ");
    name[x] = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Day of Show: ");
    day[x] = in.readLine();
    dayCount++;
    System.out.println("Enter Time of Show (ex: 2:30am = 0230) : ");
    time[x] = in.readLine();
    //Increase counter
    x++;
    //Ask if the user wants to stop
    System.out.println("\nTo continue press Enter ");
    System.out.println("To Quit, type in 'quit': ");
    }
    while((in.readLine().compareTo("quit"))!=0);

//Method addShow()    
}
```

Comment: Where do you increment any element in `showdayCount`?

Comment: Sorry, looks like I forgot about it. I have made changes to it, but it still hasn't worked. I have a hunch that I should be initializing each day in a switch statement but I have no clue how I should do it.

Comment: So you're problem is that you only have two shows on Sunday, but at the end it outputs that there is three?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't show the total shows for each day properly. For example, the output should have shown "There is 2 shows on Sunday" and in the next line "There is 1 show on Tuesday".

Comment: Could you please post the code where you increment `showdayCount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop that prints the total shows you have:

```
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    if(i ==0) {
    System.out.println("There is " + dayCount + " shows on " + day[i]);
    }
}
```

The `if(i == 0)` makes it so that the println only executes on the first iteration of the loop. Take out the if statement and have:

```
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    System.out.println("There is " + dayCount + " shows on " + day[i]);        
}
```

And this should print out the rest of the days

Also you only have one `dayCount` variable that you use for all the days. So no matter what day a show is on, you increment `dayCount`. (If you have three shows on different days you still increment `dayCount` everytime so it shows that you have three shows on each day when you print it out) If you want to have a separate `dayCount` variable for every day, I recommend using a [`Hashmap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).
(Using the day as the key and the `dayCount` as the value)

Also you could look into [`enums`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) to use for the days of the week.

Comment: Thank you, it now prints out the rest of the days. However, It isn't showing the correct amount of shows per day. For example, the output is showing that there are 3 shows on Sunday, when there are only 2.